# Image clipping with visible overflow in Fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

I want to clip image, BUT default clipping behaviour just hiding a part of image which out of border. Is there a way to make it visible and set less opacity for overflowed content?

There's one of [old clipping examples](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxYCP/198/) I told about. It also using lodash to bind clip name to object:

```
return _.bind(clipByName, pug)(ctx)
```

Is there a way to replace this functionality with vanilla es5?

Comment: there is not such a way.  you can make an hack that gives a similar result if you show a picture of what you want to obtain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found unclear solution. Again.
Background color of canvas could make an opacity and background image could be clipping object (w/o clipping by itself).
Also, loaded image shoul define `globalCompositeOperation` set to `source-atop`.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var clipingRect = new fabric.Rect({
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    top: 50,
    left: 50,
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    fill: 'white',
    selectable: false
});
canvas.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255,255,0,0.5)';
canvas.setBackgroundImage(clipingRect);
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://placeimg.com/640/480/any', function(fimg) {
    canvas.add(fimg.set({
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        width: canvas.getWidth(),
        height: canvas.getHeight(),
        globalCompositeOperation: 'source-atop'
    }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.12/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. I finally found this after searching for 2 days

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, had struggled for a week to find this solution. I made change to remove yellow and white rectangle that is seen when moving. 

canvas.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)';